# How to place widget in Joomla 3.0 as module

Tags: module

How to place widget code in Joomla 3.0 site through a module. Earlier in Joomla 2.5, I used Advanced HTML but could not locate in Joomla 3.3.

Comment: What do you mean by `widget code`? Is this short code that is provide by another extension?

Comment: By widget I meant Java Code that is provided for rotating banner by affiliate marketing companies like cj.com, linkshare.com. I have installed sourcerer extension which appears to be serving my purpose.

Answer (score 2):

- If you want to implement a well-known widget, for instance a **Facebook Like**, you can find several extensions already developed and tested in **Joomla! Extensions Directory** http://extensions.joomla.org/
- If your widget is not already developed, you look for a similar widget in **JED** and change the code to match your requirements. All extensions in JED are open source GPL.
- If your widget is very simple, you can simply install an extension to add **Custom Code in content** http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content or create a module to have the HTML and Javascript code (similar to Advanced HTML), like *NoNumber's Sourcerer*.

Answer (score 2):

The built-in Custom HTML module in Joomla can work, but if you're using TinyMCE as your editor, it will try to clean up your code, thus removing code that such Widgets might contain (usually `<script>` tags and often empty `<div>` tags).

One workaround is to use another editor ([JCE](http://joomlacontenteditor.net), [RokPad](http://www.rockettheme.com/joomla/extensions/rokpad) etc.), but this might cause problems if the module is opened later using TinyMCE again.

The easiest way to add any code is to use a custom HTML module, like [Custom HTML Advanced](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-modules/16359).